# Return data with then to controller Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Follow the code

server.js

```
    app.get('/list',function(req,res){

        console.log('/list api run')

        var data=[
    { "isActive": false, "balance": "$3,960.64", "age": 30, "eyeColor": "blue", "name": "Dawn Keith", "gender": "female", "company": "COSMOSIS", "email": "dawnkeith@cosmosis.com", "phone": "+1 (839) 437-3421", "address": "392 Clifford Place, Fontanelle, Arizona, 2687"
    },
    { "isActive": false, "balance": "$1,280.14", "age": 31, "eyeColor": "green", "name": "Bettie Eaton", "gender": "female", "company": "COMTREK", "email": "bettieeaton@comtrek.com", "phone": "+1 (861) 460-2317", "address": "203 Allen Avenue, Elrama, North Carolina, 4453"
    },
    { "isActive": true, "balance": "$2,042.37", "age": 38, "eyeColor": "green", "name": "Margie Ayala", "gender": "female", "company": "VOIPA", "email": "margieayala@voipa.com", "phone": "+1 (941) 569-2231", "address": "111 Schroeders Avenue, Suitland, Louisiana, 7042"
    },
    { "isActive": false, "balance": "$3,170.35", "age": 37, "eyeColor": "blue", "name": "Baker Townsend", "gender": "male", "company": "EVIDENDS", "email": "bakertownsend@evidends.com", "phone": "+1 (808) 500-2793", "address": "190 Just Court, Canoochee, Alabama, 325"
    }]

    res.json(data);
    })
```

controller.js

```
    var app = angular.module('appList', []);


    app.factory('contactService', function($http){
        var contactResponse = {};

        contactResponse.list=function(){
            return $http({

                method: "GET",
                url: "/list"

            })
        }

        return contactResponse; 
    })

    app.controller('contacCtrl', function($scope,contactService){

    $scope.listContact=function(){
        contactService.list().then(function(response){
            $scope.setcontact=response;
        })
    }

    })
```

Using 'success', it worked, but since this method was taken from the 1.6 api, I started using 'then', which by the way returns only 'NaN and 200'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then will return raw Http Response from the server rather than parsed data. You should change to response.data

```
$scope.listContact=function(){
        contactService.list().then(function(response){
            $scope.setcontact=response.data;
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The data you're looking for is totally in the response you got! You just don't know it.

Getting a response `200` means that it went alright, and everything that was supposed to go through, did correctly. And in that response, there is a field called `response.data` that contains what you're looking for.

source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http